# How to Prevent Cognito from Reserving Username/Email without email verification?

Tags: amazon-web-services, authentication, amazon-cognito

I am using AWS Cognito for user authentication.There is an problem that Cognito is reserving username after incomplete signup.I want to prevent user from creating username without proper authentication.because it will create a lot of junk/unused usernames.Please Help!

Answer (score 0):

At cloudwatch one can set cronjob to invoke lambda function periodically. At lambda you can write down your code to delete users which are not verified for weeks or month.

Comment: thanks for your reply buddy I have also problem in email signup..
say I signup with email and did not verify my email..after it if i re signup with same email it throw error that email already exists..I want to only reserve verified credentials.

Comment: ok. Do you wish to forcefully verify email without user clicking verification link or user must click verify link to verify their email?